What is the correct license of Computer Modern fonts and its derived works?
I wonder the licenses of Computer Modern fonts and its derived works. Wikipedia says Computer Modern is under the SIL Open Font License but the CTAN's Computer Modern page says under the Knuth License. Which is correct?
In addition to it, some derived works are under the different licenses (e.g. Latin Modern under the GUST Font License). Why?

Are you sure the fonts in the 2 references are the same? Wikipedia talks about the latest Unicode version, while the CTAN seems to refer to a much older version. Pls note that the copyright holder might have released the same font with 2 different licenses (I am not sure if this is the case here, but it is possible).

@Martin_in_AUT Pretty sure that's the answer; as the font's homepage says "The versions of fonts prior to 0.7.0 are distributed under the terms of X11 License with an exception for font embedding into documents. [...] Since version 0.7.0 the license is changed to SIL Open Font License (OFL)."

I think Knuth's "Computer Modern" is not equal to Panov's "Computer Modern Unicode fonts". The latter is a derived work. I don't know why it's possible to release under other licenses. Due to Knuth License is not viral-license?

The font as you downloaded it should be accompanied with a license of some kind. It may be in a separate file, but it should exist somewhere.
